# prestashop latest version of Firefox issue

Tags: jquery, firefox, prestashop

I am using a Prestashop theme that I purchased from TemplateMonster based upon 1.6.0.9 of Prestashop.....everything has been working fine since going live some 3 years ago.

I have recently found any issue with people using the site if they are using version 52 or higher of Firefox.

It appears that from version 52 onwards, Firefox no longer supports  Java, Microsoft Silverlight and Adobe Acrobat.

Here is the link that explains it better as I don't really understand it:

https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Problems-with-add-ons-plugins-or/Why-do-Java-Silverlight-Adobe-Acrobat-and-other-plugins-no/ta-p/31069

The problem I have is that when a customer adds a product to the shopping cart, they can then continue to keep shopping or check out.

if they continue to shop, they should be able to view whats in the shopping cart by simply hovering over it.....unfortunately, if they are using version 52 or higher of Firefox, the drop down list doesn't drop down....

Here is the website:

www.rodpenroseracing.com.au

I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me find a solution to this issue....

Thanks for your help.

Cheers
Greg

Comment: Java is not javascript. And prestashop doesn't use java. Your site is working fine (without login at least). If you are having problems with javascript, try clearing your browser cache, or prestashop cache.

Comment: Hi, Are you saying that you used version 52 or newer of Firefox and when you hovered over the shopping cart that located on the top right hand corner that it displayed a list of the products???

Comment: Yes, i tried it, and it worked. But like I said, even if there was an error in there, it would nothing to do with Firefox blocking Java and the others, because prestashop doesn't use them.

Comment: I appreciate what you are saying but I cannot get it to work on version 52 and newer but you are saying that you are seeing it work.....it is very confusing.....do you have any idea how I can figure this issue out?

Comment: Same here, Firefox 52 ans blockcart is working fine.

Comment: Then I'm at a loss.....any ideas how to track down the issue?

Comment: Guys, just to check...are you using a Windows version of Firefox or Mac?